# maven-shade-plugin: how maven shade same class in different jar?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

If my project depends on two jars, A and B, which both in turns depends on class foo.bar.FooBar. But they includes different versions of FooBar in their jars, and only work with that specific version, e.g. A depends on FooBar v1, B depends on FooBar v3.

Then when the shade plugin merges A and B into the final fat jar, how maven relocates them to ensure A and B both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you need a shaded version of both A and B first, both with their own relocated version of `foo.bar.FooBar`. Only this way A will be "recompiled" with its own FooBar version, and so is B.
After that you can create a fat jar.

Comment: But then, if I do not need to shade anything when building the top level project, I could use assembly plugin instead of shade plugin, correct?

Comment: Since shade plugin could handle resources conflict, why it do not consider resolving class conflict like what I mention?

Comment: I strongly advice to use maven-shade-plugin to create a fat jar, it is much more powerful and fits much better the requirements.

Comment: If FooBar v1 and FooBar v3 have the same groupId+artifactId, then Maven selects one (not maven-shade-plugin). When they exist in different artifacts, then maven-shade-plugin just follows the classpath rules: first occurrence wins.

Comment: But what if I could not touch the source codes of A and B, e.g. they are third-party closed source products. Why maven-shade-plugin could not shade specific package from specific jar to specific pattern? That is, could I solve my problem completely in the top level project maven?

Comment: You don't need the sources. Add a maven module like mycomp:A that only depends on thirdparty:A, select A and the foo.bar dependency for shading and specify the relocation. You can do the same for B.
As said, I expect only 1 version of FooBar on the classpath, you should verify that first. If so, your question regarding why maven-shade-plugin cannot shade specific package from specific jar to specific pattern is answered: there's only one specific jar.

Comment: @RobertScholte
I also have the problem of having a very fat jar file but no source code. I want to use maven shade plugin to modify one of the path "com.google.gson.Gson" inside the jar(and its  import command) because it conflict with a old version of gson.jar (the API changed). This old version of gson.jar is built in the Matlab and always be loaded first cannot be removed. I will try to learn how to use maven and try your solution.